# Alt+Tab in kUbuntu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, kubuntu

When I use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> in kUbuntu, I get the lame and old-fashioned interface where the focus moves through the open applications.

When I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> I want the current windows to zoom out and the next window to slide in.

I have seen this feature on a couple of other systems. How do I change the settings?

Answer (score 1):

System settings > Windows behaviour > Task Switcher.

Have a look at the [KDE wiki](http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Window_Behaviour)